# PowerShell & Get-Aduser the –in, -contains operators not get the correct result as –match operator

Tags: powershell, active-directory, operators

I don't know why the -in and -contains operator couldn't get the same correct result as -match operator.

below is the code.

```
  $user = @( "sysmon","srvctableau","ParkerE", "NguyenDi")
    
    $depart = get-aduser -filter "enabled -eq 'false'" -properties * |  Select -Property SamAccountName
    
    ForEach ($item in $user) 
    {
        if ($item -in $depart) { Write-Output "-in $item  departed" }
        else{ Write-Output "-in $item  is employee" }   
    } 
    
    ForEach ($item in $user) 
    {
        if ($depart -contains $item) { Write-Output " -contains $item  departed" }
        else{ Write-Output "-contains $item  is employee" } 
    } 
    
    ForEach ($item in $user) 
    {
        if ($depart -match $item) { Write-Output "-match $item  departed" }
        else{ Write-Output "-match $item  is employee" }    
    }
```

sysmon  is employee,
srvctableau  is employee,
ParkerE  departed,
NguyenDi  departed

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-in` and `-contains` are operators for checking if a `value` exists in a `collection`, in this case, you're comparing an `object[]` with a `value`.

You can either do this:

```
$depart = (Get-ADUser -filter "enabled -eq 'false'").sAMAccountName

# OR

$depart = Get-ADUser -filter "enabled -eq 'false'" |
          Select-Object -ExpandProperty sAMAccountName
```

Or this:

```
if ($item -in $depart.sAMAccountName){ ... }

# AND

if ($depart.sAMAccountName -contains $item){ ... }
```

Here you have an example of what you're trying to do and why it fails:

```
PS /> $test = 'one','two','three' | foreach { [pscustomobject]@{Value = $_} }

PS /> $test

Value
-----
one  
two  
three

PS /> $test -contains 'one'
False

PS /> 'one' -in $test
False

PS /> $test.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                       
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                       
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                                                                                   

PS /> $test.Value -contains 'one'
True

PS /> 'one' -in $test.Value
True
```

Comment: Thanks so much. it works now.  I have another question about

Comment: -match.  if ($depart -match '\b$item\b')  doesn't get  correct result for exact word match. what is the correct regular expression.

Comment: @clin Single quotes will not allow variable expansion, use double quotes instead `"\b$item\b"`. If this answer was helpful to you, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).